# Stuck at javascript promises inside forEach loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

lets consider dictionary that maintains score of various types, like 
    {a:0,b:0,c:0}
i have 3 collections of mongo db A,B and C.
performing,

```
A.find({<key>:<value>})
.then(res=>{
    //gets an array of the response <RES1>
})
```

Now forEach element in the array, i am doing like

```
B.find({_id : <RES1[i].some_id>})
.then(res=>{
    //again a new array of responses <RES2>
})
```

Finally, i get the type for which scores needs to be updated in collection C and i again query in a loop like

```
C.find({_id : RES2[i].some_key})....
```

I am not sure where i am wrong!!! embedding code below

```
getScoreForEachTypes() {
    User.find({ company: req.params.company })
        .then(users => {
            var responsesOfAllUsersArr = [];
            usersForThisCompany = users;
            users.forEach(user => {
                responsesOfAllUsersArr.push(Response.find({ email: user.email }));
            });
            return Promise.all(responsesOfAllUsersArr);
        })
        .then(responsesOfAllUsersArr => {
            var data = { _E: 0, _M: 0, _A: 0, _Q: 0, _E: 0 };
            responsesOfAllUsersArr.forEach(el => {
                el.forEach(_el => {
                    var j = getQuestionType(_el.questionId);
                    data[j] += _el.responseChoice;
                })
            })
        });
}

function getQuestionType(qid) {
    return Question.findOne({ _id: qid })
        .then(el => {
            return el.quesType;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("err while fetching type of question", err);
        });
}
```

Comment: How do you use `getScoreForEachTypes()`? That function doesn't have a return value.

Comment: ya, thats where i am stuck, i need its return value to use further..i need to return the updated data which would be somthing like { _E: 1, _M: 4, _A: 6, _Q: 3, _E: 0 }

Comment: What if you write `return` just before `User.find` ? (first line inside the function)

Comment: @Zyigh It will return a promise in pending state which in the logs is like `Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: Yep sorry I wasn't clear at all... What if you return the Promise (`User.find`) but write the `.then()` after the call of the function ?

Comment: Ya might work but real pain is to get the value from promise inside forEach loop, as data[j] is again adding a new key [Object Promise] with value NaN,
because getQuestionType also returns a Promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved my problem.
I just had to maintain an array.

```
function a(){
    var data = { PE: 0, RM: 0, BA: 0, AIQ: 0, FE: 0 };
    var responsesAll = [];
    var xyz = [];
    return User.find({ company: req.params.company })
        .then(users => {
            var responsesOfAllUsersArr = [];
            usersForThisCompany = users;
            users.forEach(user => {
            responsesOfAllUsersArr.push(Response.find({ email: user.email 
        }));
        });
    return Promise.all(responsesOfAllUsersArr);
    })
    .then(responsesOfAllUsersArr => {
        responsesOfAllUsersArr.forEach(el => {
            el.forEach(_el => {
                responsesAll.push(_el);
                xyz.push(getQuestionType(_el.questionId))
            })
        })
        return Promise.all(xyz);
    }).then(xyz => {
        for (var i = 0; i < xyz.length; i++) {
            data[xyz[i].quesType] += parseInt(responsesAll[i].responseChoice);
        }
        return data;
    })
}
```